# Realm Mobile Platform with big data

Tags: realm, data-synchronization, realm-mobile-platform

I'm planning to use Realm Mobile platform for mobile apps in our system.

The problem is that our system has hundreds of GBs of data. So I would like to share only some parts of that data with the mobile apps.

And now we have a scenario with the main database and the Realm Object Server where there are multiple Realm databases for each user.

I'm assuming that sharing more than 1GB of data with mobile apps, would be not reliable and could lead to worse app performance.

The question is how to approach sharing and synchronizing the data between the main database and ROS?

How to share the data so the app doesn't have to download a whole dataset related to a specific user, at the first run of application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you will probably have a hard time getting room for gigabytes of data on the mobile devices. The way forward would be to split your data up into multiple Realms (assuming there is some axis to shard the data around, like time, location or user).

Then the individual mobile devices can choose to just sync out the Realms with the data relevant to them.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. But what about server instance of Realm database. Can it handle 300GB dataset?

Comment: > what about server instance of Realm database. Can it handle 300GB dataset?

Doesn't sound like a problem. The limitations are going to be more around the number of concurrent users it can handle. If you expect to have a large number of users accessing the data at the same time, you might want to consider splitting it across multiple servers.